# How do I assign a value to an integer from a loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I am experienced in JavaScript, but not in Java.
I am trying to assign a value in a loop to a predefined variable, so I can access that after the loop is finished. Somehow, it works as long as the loop is being executed, but when the loop is finished, the value is gone.

```
    int intResult=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < jArrResult.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jObjResult = jArrResult.getJSONObject(i);
        intResult = Integer.parseInt(jObjResult.getString("response"));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response1: "+intResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response2: "+intResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You're constantly reassigning the variable every loop.

Comment: You're saying "assign **a** value" to "**a** predefined variable".  But it's a loop, so a (possibly) different value gets assigned to the one variable on each trip through; after the loop you're left with only the _last_ value that was assigned.

Comment: True, but shouldn't that be the normal way to change a value? The loop is just to get all the different keys of the JSON array, and there is just one key called "response" in that JSON array. This would mean that the value of intResult (which is 0 before the loop) changes to the value of jObjResult.getString("response"). Or doesn't it work that way?

Comment: Well what about all those other keys that aren't "response"?  What do you suppose comes back when you do `jObjResult.getString("response")` on a `JSONObject` that doesn't have a "response" key?  Probably `null`.  You need to make sure there is actually a "response" key before setting `intResult`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson That's right - I should make sure there is a "response" in future, but in the current case, there IS a "response". The JSON string is as follows:
{"result":[{"response":"1"},{"enckey":"xkmgL4rvHpx0cxtVFPCoORjEa7IVx1Ll"}]}

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I now understand what you mean! In the SECOND run of the loop, there is no "response" but only an "enckey".. And that's why the loop isn't functioning; that's why the Toast line after the loop isn't being run. Thanks! I will try to find out how to fix that. Probably by not using a loop but another way to extract values from the JSON array.

Comment: If you post your actual and mention your expected output then it would be much beneficial.

Comment: @KevinAnderson When you say "dying", do you mean "terminated"? That is not the case, the app is still running. But you've solved my problem :)
Instead of a loop, I am using the following:
JSONObject jObjResult = jArrResult.getJSONObject(0);
intResult = Integer.parseInt(jObjResult.getString("response"));
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Before loop: "+intResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

The first key in the array is always "response" with a value; 1 means "everyting is ok"
Thank you very much, Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

@KevinAnderson wrote:
Well what about all those other keys that aren't "response"? What do you suppose comes back when you do jObjResult.getString("response") on a JSONObject that doesn't have a "response" key? Probably null. You need to make sure there is actually a "response" key before setting intResult

The second run of the loop, there was no key called "sesponse", so the loop could not finish.

Now I am using the following:

```
JSONObject jObjResult = jArrResult.getJSONObject(0);
intResult = Integer.parseInt(jObjResult.getString("response"));
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Before loop: "+intResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Thanks, Kevin